# Extract data from a file into another file

Tags: regex, perl

I want to extract a file that contains data info about a person like name, address, phone.. The file can look like this:

```
Name:John
FirstName:Smith
Address:Main Street
Phone:32674632
Name:Alice
FirstName:Meyers
Address:Forth Av.
Phone:273267462
```

But sometimes the address is written on 2 lines:

```
Name:John
FirstName:Smith
Address:Main Street
Phone:32674632
Name:Alice
FirstName:Meyers
Address:Forth Av.
street 54
Phone:273267462
```

I wrote this :

```
while (<INPUT>) {
        chomp;
        if (/^Name/) {
            ($match) = /Name:(.*)/;
            $string = $string.$match." ";
            next;
        } 
        if (/^FirstName/) {
            ($match) = /FirstName:(.*)/;
            $string = $string.$match." ";
            next;
        } 
        if (/^Address/) {
            ($match) = /Address:(.*)/;
            $string = $string.$match." ";
            next;
        } 
        if (/Address:(.*)$Phone/) {
            ($match) = /Address:(.*)$phone/;
            $string = $string.$match." ";
            next;
        }
        if (/^Phone/) {
            ($match) = /Phone:(.*)/;
            $string = $string.$match." ";
            print OUTPUT "$string\n";
            $string = "";
            next;
        } 
}
```

Can anyone help me find a way to deal with those lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

my $key = '';
my %person = ();

while (<>) {                            # for each line
    chomp;
    if (/^(.+?):(.*)/) {                # Do we have a key followed by a colon?
        $key = $1;                      # the key is the part before the colon
        $person{$key} = $2;             # The value is the part after the colon
        if ($key eq 'Phone') {          # A line with a 'Phone' key is the last one for a person
            print Dumper(\%person);     # Dump our person
            $key = '';
            %person = ();               # Start a new person
        }
    } else {
        $person{$key} .= " $_";         # No key means just append this line to the value for the previous key
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I have a key that should be formed by 2 words? how can I write the regex?

Comment: With spaces in between?

Comment: Yes with white space between. And I have encountered another problem, some of the persons have 2 phone nr. I don't know how to save them, because the key must be unique so the first phone will be overwritten by the second one

Comment: I changed the regexp to accept any characters up to the colon.
Well, what do you want to happen when there is two phone numbers?

Comment: Hey I solved it. I counted how many times the phone appears and I concatenated that nr. to the key. So I would have `phone1` `phone2` ... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (/^Address/) {
        ($match) = /Address:(.*)$Phone/;
        $string = $string.$match." ";
        next;
    }
```

If your file contains same formatting that is after address the next record is phone then write your expression to search the complete string in between Address and phone. `/^Address:.*$Phone/`

Then search like this `/^Address.* [\s.*:]$/`

Start with Address and End with [space any char :]. It must have to work.

Comment: That works only if I always have `phone` after `address` . But of course that doesn't happend :(. Are in a random order. Somehow I have to figure it out to which field that row belongs and concatenate it there...

Comment: I didn't solve it. Because if I have `occupancy` or any other than `phone` after address it doesn't work. The data is random, there is not a specific order

Comment: Can you check my edited question, it still doesn't work. Maybe I miseunderstood your answer..

Answer (score 0):

```
@array=split /\nName/,<INPUT>;
while my $vals (@array) {
    chomp($vals);
    my @spls = ($1,$2,$3,$4) if($_=~/:(.*?)FirstName:(.*?)Address:(.*?)Phone:(.*)/);
    chomp(@spls);
    my $string = join(" ",@spls);
    print OUTPUT "$string\n";          
}
```